# JS - How do i run script again when new text elements are added to a page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

After browsing through StackOverflow for a while i weren't able to find a solution. For a school project we've made a chrome/firefox extension that replaces words on websites using a filter we customize ourselves. We've been able to react to URL changes, but we can't get it to update when the site updates without changing the URL, like when you scroll down on facebook or youtube and new content is automatically added.

We've tried using mutationObserver but it haven't proven succesful (No errors but no console logs either, so it isn't triggered)

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (mutation.type  === "characterData") {
            console.log(mutation.target);
        } else {
            for (var x = 0; x < mutation.addedNodes.length; x++) {
                var node = mutation.addedNodes[x];
                if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                    console.log(node);
                    walk(document.body)
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true, characterData: true });
```

Basically we just want to run our extension again once a site changes without the url updating, but we can't figure out how to. Any suggestion?

Comment: Mutation records don't necessarily include ALL of the recursively added nodes in the `addedNodes` array. The opposite is usually true: only the top node is listed so you need to enumerate its tree recursively. See [How to change the HTML content as it's loading on the page](//stackoverflow.com/a/39334319)

Comment: English is not my first language, so i'm not sure what you mean with enumerating the tree recursively. I assume you mean using for loops to go through each node? Anyway, thanks for the link, i'll see if i can figure it out from the post you linked.

Answer (score 1):

One idea could be to monkey patch the `append` function of the `Element` constructor (`Element.prototype.append`) and the `appendChild` function of the Node constructor (`Node.prototype.appendChild`). Not so great but should do the job.

```
Element.prototype.__append__ = Element.prototype.append;
Element.prototype.append = function(e){
                             console.log("Replacing some words in this element");
                             this.__append__(e);
                           };
Node.prototype.__appendChild__ = Node.prototype.appendChild;
Node.prototype.appendChild = function(e){
                               console.log("Replacing some words in this node");
                               this.__appendChild__(e);

                           };
```